# How can I show the buttons on the bottom when Menu hard-key is pressed?

Tags: android

I made buttons.xml in layout directory.
I'd like to show this on the bottom of screen when the user press 'Menu hard-key'

My current code is this.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU){
    if (mActionBar.isShowing()) {
        mActionBar.hide();
        <<Here, I want to hide buttons on the bottom>>
    }
    else {
        mActionBar.show();
        <<Here, I want to show buttons on the bottom>>
    }
}else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
    WebView  myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    myWebView.goBack();
}
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to the options menu [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu) is how you use it. You will have to move the xml from `layout` to `menu` folder.

Answer (score 1):

create a menu items like this in the menu folder

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
```

Comment: no...whenever the showAsAction set to never it will not displayed in the actionbar means top right..when you set showAsAction as always or free then it will come..